# Select Row value For calculation in java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql

i am creating loan interest calculation project. my  input page have lot  have two section compare and primary section. compare section   hide input fields.

both section have same value

primary section have  loan types Radio button

compare section have loan types Drop down box

my issues Compare box working perfectly all loan. when  select primary loan types  its not working  if select both section same value its Working fine

My primary loan  section  image

[image]

my Compare loan section value  image[image]

if user select value compare section working it s not working Radio button

```
/*state holders*/
/*WARNING!! this script must be above all other js scripts*/

var userChangedUpfrontMIPPc_ = false;
var userChangedUpfrontMIPAmt_ = false;
var userChangedMonthlyMIP_ = false;
var userChangedDownPaymentPc_ = false;
var userChangedDownPaymentAmt_ = false;
userChangedUpfrontMIP = false;
userChangedMonthlyMIP = false;
userChangedSSMonthlyMIP = false;

//state=true or false
function userChangedUpfrontMIPPc(state) {
  userChangedUpfrontMIPPc_ = state;
}
//state=true or false
function userChangedUpfrontMIPAmt(state) {
  userChangedUpfrontAmt_ = state;
}
//state=true or false
function userChangedMonthlyMIP(state) {
  userChangedUpfrontMIP_ = state;
}
//state=true or false
function userChangedDownPaymentPc(state) {
  userChangedDownPaymentPc_ = state;
}
//state=true or false
function userChangedDownPaymentAmt(state) {
  userChangedDownPaymentAmt_ = state;
}

function getMIP(str) {
  //get user input
  ficorange = document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements['ficorange'].value;
  compareloan = document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements['ddlCompare1'].value;
  loantype = document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements['loantype'].value;
  purchaseprice = document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements['purchaseprice'].value;

  downpaymentamt = "";

  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    if (document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements['loantype'][i].checked == true) {
      loantype = document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.loantype[i].value;
    }
  }

  // alert(str);
  // if(str== "Compare")
  // {   if(loantype=="jumbo")
  // {
  // downpaymentpc=document.getElementById("downpaymentConv").value;
  // document.getElementById("upfrontMIPPc1").value;
  // document.getElementById("monthlyMIPPc1").value;
  // document.getElementById("ssmonthlyMIPPc1").value;
  // }  
  // }

  if (loantype == "jumbo") {
    downpaymentpc = document.getElementById("downpaymentConv").value;
    interestrate = document.getElementById("interestrate1").value;
  }
  if (loantype == "fha") {
    downpaymentpc = document.getElementById("downpaymentFHA").value;
    interestrate = document.getElementById("interestrateCompare").value;

  }
  if (loantype == "va") {
    downpaymentpc = document.getElementById("downpaymentVA").value;
    interestrate = document.getElementById("interestrate3").value;
  }
  if (loantype == "usda") {
    downpaymentpc = document.getElementById("downpaymentUSDA").value;
    interestrate = document.getElementById("interestrate4").value;
  }
  //seconds and silent seconds
  totalseconds_ = 0.0;
  totalsilentseconds_ = 0.0;
  secondV = document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements['second'].value;
  if (secondV == "") {
    secondV = "0";
  }
  secondV_ = parseFloat(secondV);
  secondT = document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements['secondtype'].value;
  if (secondT == "normal") {
    totalseconds_ += secondV_;
  } else {
    totalsilentseconds_ += secondV_;
  }

  thirdV = document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements['third'].value;
  if (thirdV == "") {
    thirdV = "0";
  }
  thirdV_ = parseFloat(thirdV);
  thirdT = document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements['thirdtype'].value;
  if (thirdT == "normal") {
    totalseconds_ += thirdV_;
  } else {
    totalsilentseconds_ += thirdV_;
  }

  fourthV = document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements['fourth'].value;
  fourthT = document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements['fourthtype'].value;
  if (fourthV == "") {
    fourthV = "0";
  }
  fourthV_ = parseFloat(fourthV);
  if (fourthT == "normal") {
    totalseconds_ += fourthV_;
  } else {
    totalsilentseconds_ += fourthV_;
  }

  fifthV = document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements['fifth'].value;
  fifthT = document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements['fifthtype'].value;
  if (fifthV == "") {
    fifthV = "0";
  }
  fifthV_ = parseFloat(fifthV);
  if (fifthT == "normal") {
    totalseconds_ += fifthV_;
  } else {
    totalsilentseconds_ += fifthV_;
  }

  sixthV = document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements['sixth'].value;
  sixthT = document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements['sixthtype'].value;
  if (sixthV == "") {
    sixthV = "0";
  }
  sixthV_ = parseFloat(sixthV);
  if (sixthT == "normal") {
    totalseconds_ += sixthV_;
  } else {
    totalsilentseconds_ += sixthV_;
  }

  q = "ficorange=" + ficorange;
  q += "&loantype=" + loantype;
  q += "&purchaseprice=" + purchaseprice;
  q += "&downpaymentpc=" + downpaymentpc;
  q += "&downpaymentamt=" + downpaymentamt;
  q += "&seconds=" + totalseconds_;
  q += "&silentseconds=" + totalsilentseconds_;

  if (loantype == "" || purchaseprice == "" || (downpaymentpc == "" && downpaymentamt == "")) {
    //document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML= "";
    return;
  }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else {
    //code for IE6, IE5
    xlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      //alert (xmlhttp.responseText);
      var values = xmlhttp.responseText.split(",");
      if (str = "loantype") {
        if (userChangedUpfrontMIP == false) {
          if (loantype == "jumbo") {
            document.getElementById("upfrontMIPPc1").value = values[0];
            document.getElementById("monthlyMIPPc1").value = values[2];
            document.getElementById("ssmonthlyMIPPc1").value = values[6];
            // document.forms["frmCalculator"].elements["upfrontmipamt"].value="";  
            // document.forms["frmCalculator"].elements["monthlymipamt"].value="";      
            // document.forms["frmCalculator"].elements["ssmonthlymipamt"].value="";                
            //$('#monthlyMIPPc2').val(str);
          }
          if (loantype == "fha") {
            document.getElementById("upfrontMIPPc2").value = values[0];
            document.getElementById("monthlyMIPPc2").value = values[2];
            document.getElementById("ssmonthlyMIPPc2").value = values[6];
            // document.forms["frmCalculator"].elements["upfrontmipamt"].value="";  
            // document.forms["frmCalculator"].elements["monthlymipamt"].value="";      
            // document.forms["frmCalculator"].elements["ssmonthlymipamt"].value="";    
            //$('#monthlyMIPPc2').val(str);
          }
          if (loantype == "va") {
            document.getElementById("upfrontMIPPc3").value = values[0];
            document.getElementById("monthlyMIPPc3").value = values[2];
            document.getElementById("ssmonthlyMIPPc3").value = values[6];
            // document.forms["frmCalculator"].elements["upfrontmipamt"].value="";  
            // document.forms["frmCalculator"].elements["monthlymipamt"].value="";      
            // document.forms["frmCalculator"].elements["ssmonthlymipamt"].value="";    
            //$('#monthlyMIPPc2').val(str);
          }
          if (loantype == "usda") {
            document.getElementById("upfrontMIPPc4").value = values[0];
            document.getElementById("monthlyMIPPc4").value = values[2];
            document.getElementById("ssmonthlyMIPPc4").value = values[6];
            //$('#monthlyMIPPc2').val(str);
          }
        }
      }
      else {
        document.forms["frmCalculator"].elements["upfrontmippc2"].value = values[0];
        document.forms["frmCalculator"].elements["upfrontmipamt"].value = "";
        document.forms["frmCalculator"].elements["monthlymippc2"].value = values[2];
        document.forms["frmCalculator"].elements["monthlymipamt"].value = "";
        document.forms["frmCalculator"].elements["ssmonthlymippc2"].value = values[6];
        document.forms["frmCalculator"].elements["ssmonthlymipamt"].value = "";
      }
    }
    if (compareloan == "jumbo") {
      a = document.getElementById("downpaymentConv").value;
      document.getElementById("downpaymentCompare").value = a;
      b = document.getElementById("upfrontMIPPc1").value;
      document.getElementById("CompareUpfront").value = b;
      c = document.getElementById("monthlyMIPPc1").value;
      document.getElementById("CompareMonthly").value = c;
      d = document.getElementById("ssmonthlyMIPPc1").value;
      document.getElementById("ComparessMonthly").value = d;
      e = document.getElementById("interestrate1").value;
      document.getElementById("interestrateCompare").value = e;
    }
    if (compareloan == "fha") {
      a = document.getElementById("downpaymentFHA").value;
      document.getElementById("downpaymentCompare").value = a;
      b = document.getElementById("upfrontMIPPc2").value;
      document.getElementById("CompareUpfront").value = b;
      c = document.getElementById("monthlyMIPPc2").value;
      document.getElementById("CompareMonthly").value = c;
      d = document.getElementById("ssmonthlyMIPPc2").value;
      document.getElementById("ComparessMonthly").value = d;
    }
    if (compareloan == "va") {
      a = document.getElementById("downpaymentVA").value;
      document.getElementById("downpaymentCompare").value = a;
      b = document.getElementById("upfrontMIPPc3").value;
      document.getElementById("CompareUpfront").value = b;
      c = document.getElementById("monthlyMIPPc3").value;
      document.getElementById("CompareMonthly").value = c;
      d = document.getElementById("ssmonthlyMIPPc3").value;
      document.getElementById("ComparessMonthly").value = d;
    }
    if (compareloan == "usda") {
      alert(compareloan);
      a = document.getElementById("downpaymentUSDA").value;
      document.getElementById("downpaymentCompare").value = a;
      b = document.getElementById("upfrontMIPPc4").value;
      document.getElementById("CompareUpfront").value = b;
      c = document.getElementById("monthlyMIPPc4").value;
      document.getElementById("CompareMonthly").value = c;
      d = document.getElementById("ssmonthlyMIPPc4").value;
      document.getElementById("ComparessMonthly").value = d;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "getMIPs.php?" + q, true);
  //alert(q);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

this my script   i am using function variable compare loan = compare Loan 
primary loan type= loantype  its Working only comapre section  . at the same time primary section working when both section selected same value. please  any mistake in my script .. thanks in advance . if user select radio button  value select that Row of value ..

Comment: Please scale this down to the minimal code needed to represent your specific problem. A demo in jsfiddle.net that displays your problem  would also be helpful